# Use of an \if statement inside a tikz environment

Tags: ifthenelse

In order to illustrate a large chapter number on the beginning of each chapter, I created a tikz environment and added it to the CLS file like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ........
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, ] at (0.905\textwidth,1.42) {\sffamily\fontsize{130}{150}\selectfont \color{gray}\thechapter};
    ........
\end{tikzpicture}
```

By this way, the `\thechapter` numbering appears as a "0" to the Contents, List of Tables and List of Figures, which is undesirable. I want numbering to begin from the first Chapter as "1" and so on. So I added an `\if` statement like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ........
    \ifnum\value{\thechapter}>0{
        \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, ] at (0.905\textwidth,1.42) {\sffamily\fontsize{130}{150}\selectfont \color{gray}\thechapter};
    \else{};
    \fi;
    ........
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the `\thechapter` numbering totally disappeared, so obviously it seems that I do not use the `\if` statement correctly. So, which is the right way to use the `\if` statement in this case?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `\value{chapter}`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\value` wants as its argument the *name* of a counter, so you want

```
\ifnum\value{chapter}>0
  \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, ] at (0.905\textwidth,1.42) {\sffamily\fontsize{130}{150}\selectfont \color{gray}\thechapter};
\fi
```

No braces around the texts for true or false (unless you do want them, for instance in order to localize a font change). The `\else` branch can be omitted if empty.

You might find elsewhere something like `\ifnum\thechapter>0`, but this is wrong, because `\thechapter` will provide the current *representation* of the `chapter` counter, which may or may not be usable in this context. Assuming it isn't is safer; that's why `\value{chapter}` is provided: it points to the “abstract” value, independent of the representation.